# cannot release bluetooth headset on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-audiomanager, headset

I have created an Android app that uses the bluetooth headset.  But I cannot release bluetooth headset.

In particular, headset seems to be able to off, so not listen the sound from headset (active : spearker or earpiece). But cannot change the sound settings(media volume and nitification) for headset. I think so that it is not been able to release it.  Can be released by kill the process of app.

Is there a way to force the release?

Thank you.